# Error spotting : I spent nearly four and half years at harrow of which three were in the Army class

Tags: exam-questions

> I spent nearly four and half years at harrow of which three were in the Army class.

This is an error spotting question. I searched for the above sentence on google and found two different answers. One said we need to replace *nearly* with *about* and other said we need to replace *of which* with *in which* but to me both these seem to be wrong correction, I guess the error is in phrase *four and half years* it should be *four and **a** half years.* Am I correct ?

Comment: Singular nouns such as  _correction_ and _phrase_, and pronouns such as _other_, must always be preceded by a _determiner_ such as the definite article _the._ "Google" will not help you with this; practice, reading and study will.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  Omitting the article (in this case, it's "a") makes the writer sound uneducated and poorly spoken.

I spent four and a half years at Harrow, of which three were in the Army class.

-or-

I spent four and a half years at Harrow; three of those years were in the Army Class.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that another error in the original sentence is that Harrow should be capitalized. I know that you have used a capital in your answer but the OP may not have spotted that.